# Moving the window on holding Qml MouseArea

Tags: qt, qml

I want to know how to move the window by press and holding the MouseArea in Qt/QML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can expose the view widget to QML with:

```
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
QDeclarativeContext *context = viewer.rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("viewerWidget", &viewer);
```

Then modify its `pos` property to move the window:

```
MouseArea {        
    anchors.fill: parent
    property variant previousPosition        
    onPressed: {
        previousPosition = Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY)
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        if (pressedButtons == Qt.LeftButton) {
            var dx = mouseX - previousPosition.x
            var dy = mouseY - previousPosition.y
            viewerWidget.pos = Qt.point(viewerWidget.pos.x + dx, 
                                        viewerWidget.pos.y + dy)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change `property variant previousPosition` to something like `property point clickPos: Qt.point(1, 1)`.